# Delete emails using IMAP in android?

Tags: android, email, imap, pop3

I decided to use `imap` in my application to access gmail and yahoo mails as per suggested by the forum and it is working fine.

But I'm still unable to delete mails. I didn't find any implicit method to delete email(s). If any one can provide a way to do this using imap, then please post some code and useful links. I also read somewhere that we can change the flag of folder, so that email will be moved to the trash. Please provide running code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through [Java mail Api for Android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/).

Here is the code excerpt

```
String mail_host="imap.gmail.com";
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);

    Store st = s.getStore("imaps");

    st.connect(mail_host,"username@gmail.com","password");
     Folder inbox = st.getFolder("inbox");
     inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

     Message m= inbox.getMessage(1);
     m.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```